# need convert BLOB to varchar in oracle but need 400 bytes characters

Tags: plsql, ora-06502

I have BLOB datatype data in table BUT as per my requirement need varchar2 data type convert this data therefore I using utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(SC.SER_DATA,2000,1)

but when using **utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(SC.SER_DATA,2000,1)** is working fine but need 4000 byte data when used utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(SC.SER_DATA,4000) showing error

**ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long**

Answer (score 0):

Since raw can only be 2000 characters, have you tried concatenating 2 chunks of 2000 characters ?

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(SC.SER_DATA,2000,1) ||
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(SC.SER_DATA, 4000, 2001))
```

Comment: same error when used utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(SC.SER_DATA, 4000, 2001))

Comment: can't help you further. My test db has max_string_size = EXTENDED and when I go beyond the limit it doesn't error out.